# Solving a quadratic, non-linear non-homogenous recurrence relation (Heron's algorithm for finding square roots.)

Tags: recurrence-relations, radicals, newton-raphson

Consider the polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = x^2 - a$ for some constant $a$. Using Newton-Raphson, we can approximate the roots of this polynomial, which will be $\pm \sqrt{a}$, as follows:
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}\right)$$

Is there a solution to this recurrence? Substituting $x_n = {\lambda}^n$ and $x_n = A^{2^n}$ give the following equations:
$$2{\lambda}^{2n+1} = {\lambda}^{2n} + a$$
and
$$2A^{3 \cdot 2^n} = A^{2\cdot2^n} + a$$
respectively. I have tried solving both by substituting $A^{2^n} = y$ as well as
${\lambda}^{2^n} = z$, which gives a quadratic as well as a cubic. I am unable to solve the cubic, but solving the quadratic gives:
$$\lambda = \left({\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8a}}{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$$
Ofcourse, the actual equation $\lambda^{2n} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+8a}}{4}$ has $2n$ roots, and the above is just one of the roots, and there is no general formula for solving afaik for $n>2$. Does this mean that there are multiple solutions?

I have also tried using the inverse difference operator, $\Delta^{-1}$. This would give:$$x_n = \Delta^{-1}\left({\frac{a}{x_n} - \frac{x_n}{2}}\right)$$
which is just the sum from $0$ to $n$ of ${\frac{a}{x_n} - \frac{x_n}{2}}$, which again I have been unable to solve. All of this makes me feel that there isn't a solution to the recurrence given by Newton-Raphson for the case $f(x) = x^2 - a$. If this is the case, could someone please provide me a hint on how to prove this argument?

Comment: I doubt that there is a general solution except in the case where $a=2$. Then you can solve by trigonometric substitution, for example, let $b_n=x_n/\sqrt{2}$, then $c_n=\coth^{-1}b_n$.

Comment: I see. Why do you think so btw? Also, where did that substitution come from?

Comment: @CyeWaldman -- in consequence there is no proof that Heron's algorithm converges? (as I grasp your hint)

Comment: Oh, it does converge. It is not tough to prove that. A general solution means a solution in terms of elementary functions and n. (and a ofc)

Comment: @CeaealYT -- Ok, then I misconceived your query. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: thats fine, no worries.